# Difference between good & great programmers

Tags: terminology

I've read this quote somewhere:
"Good programmers write good code.
Great programmers steal great code"

What is the difference between "good" and "great"? Great is better than good?
And to be honest... I don't understand this quote...

PS: maybe the title is not explicit and my English not correct, please correct it to be proper English, thanks a lot!

Comment: to be moved to [“English language and Usage”](http://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Olivier, your question is subjective and in danger of being closed soon. More suited for discussion on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks a lot, I close it myself :) :) or I'll try to ;)

Comment: The quote is saying that it's better to find great code written by others and use it than it is to merely write 'good' code yourself.

Comment: http://translate.google.com/#en|fr|it's%20better%20to%20steal%20great%20code%20than%20to%20write%20good%20code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great programmers know that their brand-new code will likely never be as good as something that has been around for a while, presumably battle-tested in a number of different situations.